# Unable to parse JSON response in Postman

Tags: json, postman

Trying to parse this JSON response and get the id Value

```
{
    "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
    "size": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "limit": 200,
    "documents": [
        {
            "document": {
                "id": 26,
```

Using this script to parse the response and post the value as an environment variable, for some reason is not retrieving the expected response.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id", jsonData.id);
```

Although it created the id variable in the environment, the value is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: try -- var data = pm.response.json();
pm.environment.set("id", data.documents[0].document.id);

Comment: The `id` property isn't on the outermost object, it's on `.documents[0].document`. So: `postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id", jsonData.documents[0].document.id);`

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder. It works

Comment: @VladHaidan - No worries! Glad that helped. FWIW, I suggest just deleting the question, since it won't be of use to others in the future (we have [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) for that). Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Since the `id` is under an object in the `documents` array of the response, you should use this

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var id = jsonData.documents[0].document.id;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("id", id);
```

Comment: Also, you're missing out part of the path to the value. It's really best not to post an *answer* to this kind of question. It's effectively a typo and/or duplicate.